# DDNS (dynamic-dns) setup and adding a hostname to a device (to be visible on the network)

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp, dynamic-dns

1. How do I provide a fixed Hostname to my device so that a netscan can
   shows up the device name across all platforms?
2. How can I reach the device using the hostname/MAC-ID (something
   which is fixed) irrespective of the dynamically changing IP?

For example, I have 2 Raspberry-Pi and I give them hostname as Pi-1 and Pi-2 respectively (visible across all platforms). Now my router gives away dynamic IPs, so the IPs keep changing. Now how do I do a simple `ping Pi-1` and get a reply? In short,how do I set up a **DDNS** (correct me if I am wrong) to map the Hostname/MAC-ID/URL against the updated IPs.

I have an application which connects to the corresponding devices (over TCP or MQTT) and does xyz stuffs. But I don't have the luxury to lookup the current IP of my device and update my application with the same everytime I move the setup to a different network. So I will just make a hostname entry in the application saying connect to "Pi-1" and it should be able connect to Pi-1 irrespective of the ip/network/domain as long as all the allocated IPs are reachable by on another.

**N.B**: I don't want to go for static IP or dhcp reserved IP and Open source packages (if required) are preferred.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to solve your problem by consulting the ARP table.
If you do something to associate with all devices on the network first (like an **nmap** scan), you should then be able to query the ARP table for any device matching the known MAC address of your Raspberry Pi.

ie.

```
nmap 192.168.1.1/24
ip neigh show | grep AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF | cut -f1 -d" "
```